# Create dummy file referenceable by file name in Python

Tags: python

Consider this code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np, base64, io
x = np.linspace(-2, 2); plt.plot(x, x**2)

b = io.BytesIO(); plt.savefig(b); b.seek(0)
text = base64.b64encode(b.read()).decode()
```

Essentially, this will create a plot, a `io.BytesIO` stream, save the plot into the stream, then read the stream and extract it to a base64 image. The intended way to use `plt.savefig()` looks like this instead:

```py
with open("a.png", "wb") as f:
    plt.savefig(f)
```

Point is, I can provide a `BytesIO` object instead of an actual file and I can do stuff with it later on. I want to do the same thing, but given only a file name, so that it looks like this (doesn't have to use `BytesIO` though):

```py
b = io.BytesIO()
b.pretendAs("file.png") # what to put here
plt.savefig("file.png")
b.readData() # what to put here
```

Of course, something like this works:

```py
plt.savefig("file.png")
with open("file.png", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
```

However, that relies on a specific, external file. This is extremely undesirable in multiprocess environments. I want to do this because some libraries (graphviz) only allow saving images to file names. Can this be done at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`tempfile` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) to safely get a filename in a temporary directory that won't be in conflict with other callers to the same library.

```
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as f:
    plt.savefig(f)
```

The `TemporaryFile` object is a file-like object, so you can roughly treat it just like you would treat a file. And when the `with` scope ends, the file will be deleted.

If you need access to a file path (for instance, for a third-party library that needs the name of the file), you can use `NamedTemporaryFile` instead.

```
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
    plt.savefig(f)
    filename = f.name
    # Do stuff with filename
```